# Json parsing in android 2

Tags: android, json

I am calling a web service and receiving this JSON but instantiating the JSONObject class is throwing error, as you can see it contains Persian character (UTF-8) which I don't think could be reason of this problem ,

JSON:

```
{"teriffs": [
{"name":"برنز","id":"1000","prices":"3;400000-12;600000"},
{"name":"برنز","id":"1000","prices":"3;400000-12;600000"},
{"name":"نقره ای","id":"1002","prices":"3;700000-12;1000000"},
{"name":"نقره ای","id":"1002","prices":"3;700000-12;1000000"}]
}
```

ERROR:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"teriffs":
>   [{"name":"برنز","id":"1000","prices":"3;400000-12;600000"},{"name":"برنز","id":"1000","prices":"3;400000-12;600000"},{"name":"نقره
>   ای","id":"1002","prices":"3;700000-12;1000000"},{"name":"نقره
>   ای","id":"1002","prices":"3;700000-12;1000000"}]} of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

CODE :

```
   try {
         JSONStringer requestMsg = new JSONStringer().object().key("Ticket").value(TempUtil.UID).endObject();
         char[] c = CallServiceHelper.getCallService(requestMsg, "/WWWServices.svc/GetTeriffs");
          if(c!=null){
             JSONObject array = new JSONObject(new String(c));
              System.out.println(array.toString());
              return array;
                    } else {
                            return new JSONObject();
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

block

Comment: Can you share your JSON code so we can help you in isolating the issue? :)

Comment: what is the value of String json?

Comment: @SunilMishra . it contains the JSON which is loaded from web service . be sure it is not null string . it contains the JSON mentioned above .

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: I've used the http://jsonlint.com/ for evaluating the JSON , it is saying that the JSON is VALID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason:**

Some character cannot be mapped using 'MacRoman" character encoding.
Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "MacRoman" character encoding.

**Edit**

```
 String jsonString = " {\"teriffs\": [{\"name\":\"برنز\",\"id\":\"1000\",\"prices\":\"3;400000-12;600000\"},{\"name\":\"برنز\",\"id\":\"1000\",\"prices\":\"3;400000-12;600000\"},{\"name\":\"نقره ای\",\"id\":\"1002\",\"prices\":\"3;700000-12;1000000\"},{\"name\":\"نقره ای\",\"id\":\"1002\",\"prices\":\"3;700000-12;1000000\"}]}";

         try {

             String UTF8String = new String(jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(UTF8String);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("teriffs");
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("ID", jsonObject.getString("id"));
                Log.d("NAME", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                Log.d("PRICES", jsonObject.getString("prices"));

            }


         } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please ?

Comment: convert your Json string into UTF-8 Encoding String.