# Json error in connectin android to webhost

Tags: android, json

I created a json class for my android application to connect it to my webhost database, below is my code, in the end of my code I use try catch  but the problem is showing Json Parser error in log `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`, any suggestion?

```
public class JSONParser { 
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = ""; 
// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}   
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the json (or at least some of it)? Also post the logcat error exactly.

Comment: here is logcat error `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916468/json-parsing-in-android-2/17916641#17916641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, you use the same character encoding here:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

as the server uses. Most likely it is not ISO 8859-1. Also (although unrelated to the problem), a buffer size of 8 bytes is ridiculously low.

Comment: well I am new to andoid, I just copied and pasted this code for web, how can I solve this problem? what should I put instead of iso-8859-1?

Comment: Which character encoding is the server using when it sends out the JSON? Put that one, it is probably UTF-8 but since I don't know the server ...

Comment: tnx, I changed iso-8859-1 with UTF-8 , and it works? what about 8? what do you suggest?

Comment: I would use at least 1024. If your JSON is typically larger than that use more.

Comment: well, solve the problem but there is a new error `parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: @AmirSadegh make it another question, and include the Json you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
json = sb.toString();
```

**with**

```
json = new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

or

Use **UTF-8** instead of **iso-8859-1**

Comment: still having the same problem and my characters are english not any other language

Comment: and for loging I use a string as username and a string as password like: amir arcane

Comment: How can I open localhost url in my desk. please add json output

Comment: I am new to Json and android, how to add json output?

Comment: `System.out.println(sb.toString());`